# Proving $\{ a^n b^m \mid n \leq m^2 \}$ is not context-free using pumping lemma

Tags: context-free, pumping-lemma

I am working on a pumping lemma question and trying to prove that the following is not context-free, but I can't finish the proof.
The language is

$$L =  \{ a^n b^m \mid n \leq m^2 \}$$

Assume Demon picks $p$ and I choose $s = a^{p^2}b^p$ and $s = uvwxy$ such that $p \geq |vwx|$.

The first case is $vwx = b^j$. If we choose $i = 0$ everything is ok and the relationship isn't right.

The second case is $vwx = a^j$. If we choose $i = 2$ every thing is ok.

I get stuck when  $vwx = a^j b^k$. How can I finish the proof in this case?

Did I choose the right string? I repeated them for $s =  a^{p}b^p$ but it didn't work.

Comment: Is the condition $n \le m^2$ or $n \ge m^2$?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I think it is indeed $n\leq m^2$, since it is coherent with the first two cases: removing $b$'s prove the word is not in $L$, and it is the same when adding $a$'s.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus it's n≤m2. question edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $vwx = a^j b^k$, there are two possibilities:

- $v$ contains both $a$s and $b$s, or $x$ contains both $a$s and $b$s. In this case $uv^2wx^2y \notin a^*b^*$, and in particular $uv^2wx^2y \notin L$.
- $v = a^s$ and $x = b^t$, where $s,t>0$ and $s+t \leq p$ (since $|vwx| \leq p$). In this case, $uv^0wx^0y = a^{p^2-s}b^{p-t}$, and so $p^2 - s \leq (p-t)^2 \leq (p-1)^2$, which translates to $s \geq 2p-1$, which is impossible, since $s \leq p-1$.

Comment: I don't understand the first one. We are not sure about the amounts of a or b in v and x.

Comment: They don't matter. What matters is that after pumping, you're not of the form $a^*b^*$.

Comment: for example v = a  and x = abbb when i = 2 uv^2wx^2y is a member of language .

Comment: What word do you start with? And what does $uv^2wx^2y$ look like?

Comment: Can you give an example? I say it's not a form of {a^nb^m∣n≤m2}

Comment: Isn't it enough just to know the v and x?

Comment: Suppose $s = a^9b^3$, and you break it up as $u = \epsilon$, $v = a$, $w = a^7$, $x = ab^3$, $y = \epsilon$. Then $uv^2wx^2y = a^2a^7ab^3ab^3 = a^{10}b^3ab^3$, which is not of the form $a^*b^*$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. I gave a complete proof. You claim that there is a shorter proof. You need to write the proof, and if it works, great.

Comment: I got it. thanks.